# Create a Web part allowing the user to choose one of three Infopath forms

Tags: infopath

I have 3 sharepoint list covering three different projects (project A,B & C) and all three list have the same columns (date of completion, team leader, Secondary contact). I have created 3 Infopath forms to edit each list.

I want to create a Web page that displays a single InfoPath form that covers all three projects (all three forms in one form) so that the users would conveniently edit any of the 3 project’s fields without having to navigate to each list and manually edit.

So is it possible to create an info path form that starts off with a dropdown box that links to the other forms? (ex. Drop down: select (project A,B or C))